# Function with vectors not working properly

Tags: c++, function, vector

When I call the function for the first time it works fine.

But when I call the function for the second time it just jumps over first part of the code, where I am trying to add a new name to the vector vec_name and sends me to the for loop.

```
void addNewStudent(int num) 
{
    string name;
    cout << "Add new student" << endl;
    cout << "Name : ";
    getline(cin, name);

    vec_name.push_back(name);   

    float avg = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
    {
        float temp;
        cout << endl << "Enter " << i << " grade : ";
        cin >> temp;
        avg += temp;
    }
    avg /= num;

    vec_avg.push_back(avg);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

I added cin.ignore() at the end of the function.

```
void addNewStudent(int num) 
{
    string name;
    cout << "Add new student" << endl;
    cout << "Name : ";

    getline(cin, name);

    vec_name.push_back(name);   

    float avg = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
    {
        float temp;
        cout << endl << "Enter " << i << " grade : ";
        cin >> temp;
        avg += temp;
    }
    avg /= num;

    vec_avg.push_back(avg);

    cin.ignore();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
cin >> temp;
```

into

```
cin >> temp >> skipws;
```

Calling `getline` (in the second function call) after `cin` (of the first function call) will read an empty string (the newline of the previous `cin`). Using `skipws` resolves the problem.

Comment: it didn't help, but after reading your answer I found cin.ignore() tnx

Comment: Yeah, or `cin.clear();`. But `skipws` usually works.@user3350597